# Change Color row with Ajax on Select Option

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to change the color Row based on a selected option.
I am able to change the select option and send the data to the database with AJAX, so i dont need to reload the page. But I cannot change the color row.

Function:

```
function on_status_update(element){ 
    var value = $(element).val();
    var rowID = $(element).attr("row");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'somepage.php', 
        data: {
            update: value,
            id: rowID,
            func: 'status'
        },
        success: function (response) {
            let row = $("select[row='".concat(response.id, "']")).parent().parent();
            row.addClass('blue');
            console.log(response); 
        }}, "json")}
```

Table:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       $job_id = $row['id'];
       echo "<form action='' method=post>";
        echo "<tr style='background-color:".$color." ; class='info status_".$row['status']."'>

                    <input type=hidden name=hidden value=" . $row['id'] . ">
                    <td class='id'>" . $row['id'] . "</td> 
                   <td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row['number'] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row['device'] . "  </td>
                    <td>" . $row['problem'] . "</td>
              <td>

     <select onchange='on_status_update(this)' row='" . ($row['id']) . "' id='status'   class='form-control col-sm-10' name='status'>
                    <option value='new' ". ($row['status'] == 'new'? 'selected ': '') .">New</option>
                    <option value='progress' ". ($row['status'] == 'progress'? 'selected ': '') .">Progress</option>
                    <option  value='wait' ". ($row['status'] == 'wait'? 'selected ': '') .">Wait</option>
                    <option  value='deler_bestilt' ". ($row['status'] == 'deler_bestilt'? 'selected ': '') .">Deler bestilt</option>
                    <option  value='deler_trenger' ". ($row['status'] == 'deler_trenger'? 'selected ': '') .">Deler trenger</option>
                    <option value='done' ". ($row['status'] == 'done'? 'selected ': '') .">Done</option>
                    <option value='close' ". ($row['status'] == 'close'? 'selected ': '') .">Close</option>
                    <option value='cancel' ". ($row['status'] == 'cancel'? 'selected ': '') .">Cancel</option>
                </select>
```

The row should change color when you change the value of the select option.

Comment: So the problem is only in `success` method? Can you post please sample `response` and `row` variables?

Comment: I might be wrong but I think to change the color I should do it in the success method of AJAX. Before I was doing it in the while cycle and it was working but that require to reload the page. And this is what I want to achieve.

Comment: That's right. I asked you to provide at least example of `row` variable. Are you sure that it exists? Have you tried to debug it?

Comment: I dont get how to do that. I was able to make it work simply coding the style color and a class tr style='background-color:".$color." , but I dont get where and how to code the style in AJAX. I only guess that is there i have to work since is there the asyncron changes happen. (I was able to code the changing of an option value with AJAX)